# Flash crashes on Browsers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm developing a flash game in cs5 and it works fine on the offline player. When running in browsers, they crash. The game is has a multifile loader and basically when all the files are almost loaded, the browser crashes. 
At first, it was only working on IE. Then i made some modifications and it was only working on FF 5.0.1 . It never runned on chrome or safari. 
On another computer with IE8, and finally, the flash gave me a stack trace:

[Stack trace from IE](https://twitter.com/nakitoss/status/101756807600541696/photo/1/large)

Then I got some stack traces on FF, and I managed to change some class names and another minor stuff and it worked on FF perfectly. But not on IE or chrome.

So I downloaded and installed the debugger version of flash player 10.3, but now on FF it finishes loading and then I get a crash message ( :( )from ff.

Does anyone have passed through it? What it could be?

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't show

Comment: I very much recommend two addons/plugins for firefox. They are **FlashBug** and **FlashFireBug**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FlashBug to see where it crashes. I found the source problem. It looks like a flash bug, or something I not doing well:

```
if ( vFunctionsMouseClick[mc] == null){ 
    var v:Vector.<Function> = new Vector.<Function>();
    vFunctionsMouseClick[mc] = v;
    vFunctionsMouseClick[mc].push(f);
}
```

vFunctionsMouseClick is an Array and mc is a MovieClip and I feel that using it as a Vector index may not be so good. But it only got me problem now.